# How to dynamically assign headers to a csv file using CsvMapper in Java

Tags: java, csv, mapping, jackson-dataformat-xml

Can anyone help please?
I am stuck on reading a csv file and serializing it onto a POJO.
I am using CsvMapper from jackson library. The reading and serialization part are done and works fine-ish. The issue is when the user moves the headers/columns around causing the serialization to make some alphabetical assumption that the values on the CSV file are also alphabetically.
Eg (File below has headers on the first row and the second row has person details values)

`personNameHeader,personAgeHeader
Wiliam,32`

Now my POJO is as follow

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
// @JsonPropertyOrder(value = {"personNameHeader", "personAgeHeader" })
public class PersonDetailsCSVTemplate  {

@JsonProperty("personNameHeader")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("personAgeHeader")
private String age;

//Public constructor and getters and setters...
```

This is the code to read the values from the CSV and map onto the class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;
...

    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();    
    CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.typedSchemaFor(PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.class).withHeader();
          MappingIterator<PersonDetailsCSVTemplate  > dataIterator = csvMapper.readerFor(PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.class).with(schema)
            .readValues(data);

     while (dataIterator.hasNextValue()) {
        PersonDetailsCSVTemplate dataCSV = dataIterator.nextValue();
}
```

After the serialization it can be seen that CsvMapper mapped the following:
`PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.name = "32"` and`PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.age = "Wiliam"`

By annotating the class with `@JsonPropertyOrder(value = {"personNameHeader", "personAgeHeader" })` forces the CSV to be always name column followed by age column which isnt ideal.

Can anyone suggest anything that they think will work?
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [sortedBy](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-csv/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/csv/CsvSchema.html#sortedBy(java.lang.String...)) and give it the order in which the properties apeare in your csv data:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonPropertyOrder(value = { "personNameHeader", "personAgeHeader" })
static class PersonDetailsCSVTemplate
{
    @JsonProperty("personNameHeader")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("personAgeHeader")
    private String age;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "PersonDetailsCSVTemplate [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }
}
```

You can keep or leave `@JsonPropertyOrder` it won't affect the output.

```
@Test
public void sort() throws IOException
{
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = csvMapper
        .typedSchemaFor(PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.class)
        .withHeader()
        .sortedBy("personNameHeader", "personAgeHeader")
        .withColumnSeparator(',')
        .withComments();

    MappingIterator<PersonDetailsCSVTemplate> dataIterator =
        csvMapper
            .readerFor(PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.class)
            .with(schema)
            .readValues("personNameHeader,personAgeHeader\r\n"
                +
                "Wiliam,32\r\n");

    while (dataIterator.hasNextValue())
    {
        PersonDetailsCSVTemplate dataCSV = dataIterator.nextValue();

        System.out.println(dataCSV);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
PersonDetailsCSVTemplate [name=Wiliam, age=32]
```

Comment: Super, thank you very much that is exactly what I needed. You just saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Following the suggestion above, I added a new method to get the headers from the file and set as sortedBy().

Comment: `/**
     * Get headers from file string [ ].
     * @param csvData the csv data
     * @return the string [ ]
     * @throws IOException the io exception
     */
    private String[] getHeadersFromFile(final byte[] csvData) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(csvData);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, UTF_8));
        String firstLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        return firstLine.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
    }`

Comment: That's one way to do it, although it is strange that the order may change...  just make sure that the header is available and that it is in the first line (leading empty lines?) and don't forget to clode the input stream, use the try-with-resource feature.

Answer (score 11):

Since Jackson 2.7, you can use `withColumnReordering(true)` instead of `sortedBy()`

```
CsvSchema schema = csvMapper
    .typedSchemaFor(PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.class)
    .withHeader()
    .withColumnReordering(true);
```

Comment: Given the OPs question is to dynamically assign headers (not statically write the order), this should be the new accepted answer imo

Comment: Thank you this is working good !